# How to Accept ONLY Two Keys Before User :Submit?

Tags: ruby

I want people to be able to challenge their habits. If they miss a day they may put "/" if they miss two days in a row they must put "X". Three X's means they failed the challenge.

How can I force the User to only be able to submit X's and /'s as valid keys in the `:missed` input field?

**_form excerpt**

```html
<%= simple_form_for(@habit) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :missed %>
      
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Github**: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Thanks in advance for your help. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select tag to limit users' options like this

```
<%= select_tag(:missed , options_for_select([['/', '/'], ['X', 'X']])) %>
```